# Homepage introduction panel proposal

Tags: discussion, feature-request

I notice that some other stacks, like [area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/) and [stack exchange central](http://stackexchange.com/), have an introduction box on their homepage's (stack central's is removable).

Perhaps if we introduced a feature like this we could use it to better explain the line between ourselves stackoverflow and serverfault, thereby avoiding so many inappropriate questions, better educating our newbie users and providing a better experience overall.

Thoughts?

Comment: You already have something like this that appears for new users: http://i.imgur.com/3qCXt.png

Comment: Indeed we do, but it is well outside of the space which user normally pay attention to and doesn't address what KIND of questions to ask.

Answer (score 1):

I have a better solution, which has been implemented on stack overflow (it only shows for low rep users)

[image: how to ask stack overflow page]

We could implement something like that too.

## UPDATE:

Here is a draft of what the introductory tect could look like. Feel free to edit it and improve it (based off of stackoverflow's)

### How to ask

Welcome to Webmasters Stack Exchange!

We’d love to help you. But not every question on Stack Overflow gets answered. To improve your chances, here are some tips:

#### Do your homework

Have you **[thoroughly searched for an answer](http://www.webmasters.stackexchange.com/search)** *before* asking your question? Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you found and why it didn't meet your needs. This demonstrates that you've taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps *you* get a more specific and relevant answer!

#### Be specific

If you ask a vague question, you'll get a vague answer. But if you give us details and context, we can provide a *useful* answer.

#### Make it relevant to others

We like to help as many people at a time as we can. Make it clear how your question is relevant to more people than just you, and more of us will be interested in your question and willing to look into it.

#### Be on-topic

Our community is defined by a specific set of topics in [the faq](http://www.webmasters.stackexchange.com/faq); please try to stick to those topics. If your question is about the site itself, ask on [our meta-discussion site](http://meta.webmasters.stackexchange.com). If you’re looking for a different topic, it might be covered on another [Stack Exchange site](http://stackexchange.com/sites).

Comment: It's not a bad plan, but doesn't that show up on our site during newbie sign up?

Comment: @toomanyairmiles No, it doesn't.

Comment: As long as you make it attractive enough and simply worded so people will actually read the damn thing. Btw, +1 to toomanyairmiles for his comment on danlefree's answer... first impressions DO matter.

Comment: @toomanyairmiles feel free to edit this text and improve it.

Answer (score 0):

I do not believe that the introduction box should be used to direct askers off-site, though I am not against the idea of adding an introduction which defines the scope of questions this site hosts (perhaps with a link to the FAQ for further reading?).

Comment: Agreed. Though our audience seems in large part to be newbies for whom English isn't a first language. Stack as a whole and our site in particular may be better off bringing them in to the fold with the right directions, rather than leaving them with a frustrating experience - first impressions matter.